# OVH cron jobs / Symfony Command

Tags: php, api, symfony, cron, ovh

I'm developing a Symfony project and I've 4 commands which allows me to update telephony and emails data thanks to OVH' Api. When I use my terminal on local ( **php bin/console converseo:updateTelephony** ) the command works fine.

Now, I want to put these commands in  crontab with the cron interface from Ovh. I made a php file **test.php** :

```
<?php
shell_exec("sh test.sh");

 ?>
```

And **test.sh** :

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/php5.6/bin/php /homez.number/mysite/www/bin/console converseo:updateBilling
```

And I get the error :

```
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]  
Command "converseo:updateBilling" is not defined.              
Did you mean one of these?                                      
      converseo:updateBilling                                     
      converseo:updateEmailCount                                  
      converseo:updateTelephony                                   
      converseo:updateEmail
```

The lines are **EXACTLY** the sames, I don't understand why I get this error.

Thanks a lot for yours answers !

Comment: Double check if you deployed all code to hosting, maybe you forgot something

Comment: I thinks i'ts ok cause when I do **php bin/console converseo:updateTelephony** the command works.. I get error only in cron

Comment: hard to say anything I have command tasks:notify and it works in local windows machine and in server cron on linux machine, only difference is that command is in lowercase and you have camelCase

Comment: The most problems with commands appear when command class does not end with Command suffix or when people do not register bundle with command, but if it works on local machine for you then its not the case

Comment: Ok I will try without camelCase :)

Comment: And my command class is **updateTelephonyCommand**

Comment: And how about your filename, does it not start from uppercase UpdateTelephonyCommand? because linux machine is sensitive for uppercase/lowercase letters in filenames when talking about autoloaders

Comment: my filename is **updateTelephonyCommand.php**

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same error with uppercase..

Comment: Interesting situation, without getting hands on I can not help anymore, when you will find out post the update what you did.

Comment: I think I resolved my problem by using : `<?php
exec("/usr/local/php5.6/bin/php /home/site/www/bin/console converseo:updatetelephony");
?>`  Thanks !